# Error when renaming variable: The getter 'units' was called on null

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

So basically, I'm trying to refactor the name of a variable (`shift + f6`) inside a class, but when doing so I get:

```
The getter 'units' was called on null. 
Receiver: null
Tried calling: units
```

Note that this is an `Android Studio` error, so I'm guessing this is probably some issue with `Dart Analysis Server`

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalidating cache and restarting, followed by restarting `Dart Analysis Server` did the trick:

[image]
[image]